# .net core async/await tcp with linux

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, epoll

I try to write simple echo server with .net and linux with code

```
    static async Task soc() {
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 8888);
        listener.Start();
        for (;;) {
            logger.LogInformation("Wait new connetcion");
            using(var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync())
            {
                logger.LogInformation("Get new connection");
                echo(client);
                client.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    static async void echo(TcpClient client) {
        var buf = new byte[512];
        using(var stream = client.GetStream())
        {
            var i = await stream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, 512);

            if (i < 1) {
                return;
            }

            await stream.WriteAsync(buf, 0, 512);
        }
    }
```

When i use async/await tcp functions like stream.ReadAsync on linux - .net use epoll or plain sockets?

Comment: Are you asking about how the .NET runtime implements async sockets on Linux? The runtime is open-source, why not go look for yourself?

Comment: You are completely rights. .net on linux use epool for async operations https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Native/Unix/System.Native/pal_networking.c

Comment: Feel free to add a short descriptive answer with your findings.

Answer (score 4):

.net core use epoll for async operation on linux, [you can see it in runtime sources](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/release/2.1/src/Native/Unix/System.Native/pal_networking.c)